# Read more/less slide toggle issue?

Tags: jquery, html, css, click, slidetoggle

I can not this toggle read more or less slide toggle to work. I'm very close but I'm not sure how to display the `#show-about` anchor so it shows `"read more"` first?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/xhLU7/2/)

```
$('#show-about').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#about-hidden').slideToggle();
$(this).text( $(this).text() == 'Read More' ? "Show Less" : "Read More");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the original text in your markup.

```
<a href="#" id="show-about">Read More</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xhLU7/4/

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
<a href="#" id="show-about">More...</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="#" id="show-about">Read More</a>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xhLU7/3/)**

It would appear that your problem stems from `$(this).text() == 'Read More' ? "Show Less" : "Read More"` and your link having the text `More...`. When you click the link, `$(this).text()` equals `More...`, however you're comparing it to `Read More`, so change the link to match that and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `jQuery` like:

**JS**

```
$('#show-about')
    .text('Read More')
    .click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#about-hidden').slideToggle();
         $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Read More' ? "Show Less" : "Read More");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhLU7/6/)

---

But, in case you can modify the HTML markup and have full acess to it, you can just do this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="show-about">Read More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you just not write to anchor "Read More" instead of "More..."?